# php calendar and multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, calendar

I have an array of calendar dates, and an multidimensional array of reports where the key to the reports is the date

Array of calendar dates structure

```
  Array
  (
      [1] => 2014-05-01
      [2] => 2014-05-02
      [3] => 2014-05-03
      [4] => 2014-05-04
      [5] => 2014-05-05
      [6] => 2014-05-06
      [7] => 2014-05-07
      [8] => 2014-05-08
      [9] => 2014-05-09
      [10] => 2014-05-10
      [11] => 2014-05-11
      [12] => 2014-05-12
      [13] => 2014-05-13
      [14] => 2014-05-14
      [15] => 2014-05-15
      [16] => 2014-05-16
      [17] => 2014-05-17
      [18] => 2014-05-18
      [19] => 2014-05-19
      [20] => 2014-05-20
      [21] => 2014-05-21
      [22] => 2014-05-22
      [23] => 2014-05-23
      [24] => 2014-05-24
      [25] => 2014-05-25
      [26] => 2014-05-26
      [27] => 2014-05-27
      [28] => 2014-05-28
      [29] => 2014-05-29
      [30] => 2014-05-30
      [31] => 2014-05-31
     )
```

And my Array of reports structure

```
 Array
  (
[2014-05-01] => Array
    (
        [0] => 16
        [1] => 17
        [2] => 18
        [3] => 20
        [4] => 21
        [5] => 22
        [6] => 15
        [7] => 14
        [8] => 13
        [9] => 1
        [10] => 3
        [11] => 4
        [12] => 5
        [13] => 12
    )

[2014-05-03] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 4
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 1
        [4] => 40
    )

[2014-05-11] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 4
        [3] => 3
        [4] => 7
        [5] => 8
        [6] => 9
        [7] => 10
        [8] => 6
        [9] => 1
    )

[2014-05-17] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 10
        [2] => 9
        [3] => 8
        [4] => 7
        [5] => 6
        [6] => 2
        [7] => 5
        [8] => 4
        [9] => 1
    )

[2014-05-18] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 1
    )

[2014-05-19] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 4
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 1
    )

[2014-05-20] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 9
        [2] => 8
        [3] => 7
        [4] => 6
        [5] => 2
        [6] => 5
        [7] => 4
        [8] => 3
        [9] => 10
    )

[2014-05-26] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 3
        [2] => 4
        [3] => 5
    )

[2014-05-27] => Array
    (
        [0] => 10
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 4
        [4] => 5
        [5] => 9
        [6] => 1
        [7] => 6
        [8] => 8
        [9] => 7
    )

  )
```

Now i want to loop through the calendar and for every value in the calendar array (the date) that matches the key of the report array (eg the date), i want to attach the reports to calendar value and use the value calendar as a key to the reports other wise i want to add a string saying no reports done.

heres how i though i might go about

```
    foreach ($calendar as $cal) 
    {
        foreach ($report as $key => $rdate) 
        {
            if ($key == $cal) 
            {
                $calendar[][$cal] = $rdate;
            }
        }
    }
```

this however just adds them to the end of the calendar array and not where the calendar value and report key match.

Like so

```
  Array
 (
[1] => 2014-05-01
[2] => 2014-05-02
[3] => 2014-05-03
[4] => 2014-05-04
[5] => 2014-05-05
[6] => 2014-05-06
[7] => 2014-05-07
[8] => 2014-05-08
[9] => 2014-05-09
[10] => 2014-05-10
[11] => 2014-05-11
[12] => 2014-05-12
[13] => 2014-05-13
[14] => 2014-05-14
[15] => 2014-05-15
[16] => 2014-05-16
[17] => 2014-05-17
[18] => 2014-05-18
[19] => 2014-05-19
[20] => 2014-05-20
[21] => 2014-05-21
[22] => 2014-05-22
[23] => 2014-05-23
[24] => 2014-05-24
[25] => 2014-05-25
[26] => 2014-05-26
[27] => 2014-05-27
[28] => 2014-05-28
[29] => 2014-05-29
[30] => 2014-05-30
[31] => 2014-05-31
[32] => Array
    (
        [2014-05-01] => Array
            (
                [0] => 16
                [1] => 17
                [2] => 18
                [3] => 20
                [4] => 21
                [5] => 22
                [6] => 15
                [7] => 14
                [8] => 13
                [9] => 1
                [10] => 3
                [11] => 4
                [12] => 5
                [13] => 12
            )

    )

[33] => Array
    (
        [2014-05-03] => Array
            (
                [0] => 5
                [1] => 4
                [2] => 3
                [3] => 1
                [4] => 40
            )

    )

[34] => Array
    (
        [2014-05-11] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2
                [1] => 5
                [2] => 4
                [3] => 3
                [4] => 7
                [5] => 8
                [6] => 9
                [7] => 10
                [8] => 6
                [9] => 1
            )

    )

[35] => Array
    (
        [2014-05-17] => Array
            (
                [0] => 3
                [1] => 10
                [2] => 9
                [3] => 8
                [4] => 7
                [5] => 6
                [6] => 2
                [7] => 5
                [8] => 4
                [9] => 1
            )

    )

[36] => Array
    (
        [2014-05-18] => Array
            (
                [0] => 4
                [1] => 5
                [2] => 3
                [3] => 1
            )

    )

[37] => Array
    (
        [2014-05-19] => Array
            (
                [0] => 5
                [1] => 4
                [2] => 3
                [3] => 1
            )

    )

[38] => Array
    (
        [2014-05-20] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 9
                [2] => 8
                [3] => 7
                [4] => 6
                [5] => 2
                [6] => 5
                [7] => 4
                [8] => 3
                [9] => 10
            )

    )

[39] => Array
    (
        [2014-05-26] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 3
                [2] => 4
                [3] => 5
            )

    )

[40] => Array
    (
        [2014-05-27] => Array
            (
                [0] => 10
                [1] => 2
                [2] => 3
                [3] => 4
                [4] => 5
                [5] => 9
                [6] => 1
                [7] => 6
                [8] => 8
                [9] => 7
            )

    )

   )
```

instead of this i would like this

```
Array (
       [1] => 2014-05-01 => Array
                            (
                            [0] => 16
                            [1] => 17
                            [2] => 18
                            [3] => 20
                            ...........
                     )
```

I think where i have been bashing my head against a wall i cant see the woods from the trees.

Any help would be grand or guidence would be grand.

regards Mike

Comment: "i want to attach the reports to calendar value and use the value calendar as a key to the reports" => isn't this part (without the subsequent "add no reports") exactly what you already have in your reports array? `[1] => 2014-05-01 => Array (...)`  doesn't make sense. You can't have *two* keys. So can't the problem be reduced to simply "I want to fill in the reports array for the dates it does not already contain"?

Comment: Thanks for your reply i wasnt thinking straight.if you check my answer you kinda hit the nail on the head. programming needs structures thought which sometimes i lack.

Answer (score 0):

So by writing this out i must of figured it out so it actually helped me just by forming the question, this is what i changed

```
    foreach ($dates_month_with_reports as $cal) 
    {
        foreach ($reportdates as $key => $rdate) 
        {
            if ($key == $cal) 
            {
                            //took away the extra array 
                $dates_month_with_reports[$cal] = $rdate;
            }
        }
    }
```

and in the calendar array i added the date to the key aswell which now gives me this

```
Array
(
[2014-05-01] => Array
    (
        [0] => 16
        [1] => 17
        [2] => 18
        [3] => 20
        [4] => 21
        [5] => 22
        [6] => 15
        [7] => 14
        [8] => 13
        [9] => 1
        [10] => 3
        [11] => 4
        [12] => 5
        [13] => 12
    )

[2014-05-02] => 2014-05-02
[2014-05-03] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 4
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 1
        [4] => 40
    )

[2014-05-04] => 2014-05-04
[2014-05-05] => 2014-05-05
[2014-05-06] => 2014-05-06
[2014-05-07] => 2014-05-07
[2014-05-08] => 2014-05-08
[2014-05-09] => 2014-05-09
[2014-05-10] => 2014-05-10
[2014-05-11] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 4
        [3] => 3
        [4] => 7
        [5] => 8
        [6] => 9
        [7] => 10
        [8] => 6
        [9] => 1
    )

[2014-05-12] => 2014-05-12
[2014-05-13] => 2014-05-13
[2014-05-14] => 2014-05-14
[2014-05-15] => 2014-05-15
[2014-05-16] => 2014-05-16
[2014-05-17] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 10
        [2] => 9
        [3] => 8
        [4] => 7
        [5] => 6
        [6] => 2
        [7] => 5
        [8] => 4
        [9] => 1
    )

[2014-05-18] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 1
    )

[2014-05-19] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 4
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 1
    )

[2014-05-20] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 9
        [2] => 8
        [3] => 7
        [4] => 6
        [5] => 2
        [6] => 5
        [7] => 4
        [8] => 3
        [9] => 10
    )

[2014-05-21] => 2014-05-21
[2014-05-22] => 2014-05-22
[2014-05-23] => 2014-05-23
[2014-05-24] => 2014-05-24
[2014-05-25] => 2014-05-25
[2014-05-26] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 3
        [2] => 4
        [3] => 5
    )

[2014-05-27] => Array
    (
        [0] => 10
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 4
        [4] => 5
        [5] => 9
        [6] => 1
        [7] => 6
        [8] => 8
        [9] => 7
    )

[2014-05-28] => 2014-05-28
[2014-05-29] => 2014-05-29
[2014-05-30] => 2014-05-30
[2014-05-31] => 2014-05-31
 )
```

I appologize for wasting your time i didnt mean to, but after i wrote the question a figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
$calendar1 = array();
foreach ($calendar as $cal) 
{
    foreach ($report as $key => $rdate) 
    {
        if ($key == $cal) 
        {
            $calendar1[][$cal] = $rdate;
        }
    }
}
```